# How can i Round in Excel

Tags: excel, rounding

Whenever the decimal remainder is less than .56 I want to round down *(normally decimals between and including 0.50 to 0.55 would round up).*

for example:

4,55 **rounds down** to  4, and
4,56 **rounds up** to  5

I have a lot of numbers (8,55;13,56;...)
Thank you

Comment: Here's what you do before asking here: you go to a search engine, type your question, and you get a list of possibly relevant results. That's what I did, and I got the answer below, probably in less time than it took to ask the question on SO. Try it - it's easy! (If after searching and trying to find a solution yourself you *still* can't find a way to do it, *then* come here and tell us what you tried; we can help you much better *if* you show some effort. "I'm too lazy to Google it" is considered kind of rude around here)

Comment: Why 4.55 to 4 usually that would round to 5 if there is any rounding up. What number rounds down and the next up?

Comment: Not to mention that Excel has an excellent built-in interactive help system; how was *that* not useful?

Comment: Of course i google it, but i cannot find it. Probbably you dont understand me. I have a lot of numbers and i want to round it, if the number is ,55 to down and if number is ,56 to up. I dont want to round it at ,50

Comment: @JanOlMajti: Ah, okay, I have misunderstood you, then. Sorry for being needlessly rude.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this odd rounding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting way of rounding but there are multiple solutions:

The 'clean' way to do it:

```
=IF(MOD(4.55; 1) > 0.55; ROUNDUP(4.55;0); ROUNDDOWN(4.55;0))
```

The short and nasty way to do it

```
=ROUND(4.55 - 0.06; 0)
```

Comment: the "clean" way is no cleaner - arguably a fair bit more messier - than your second short and sharp effort (+1 btw for the second effort)

Comment: (opinion I guess): I called the first one clean because the result of the formula is immediately obvious (anything over .55 is rounded up). In the second (shorter) case that is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so we first detect whether the decimal is greater than .55, so lets get that (say it's in cell A1). Then we call the appropriate method.

```
// Get the decimal value, is it greater than 0.55?
if (A1 - INT(A1) > 0.55)
{
  RoundUp(A1, 0);
}
else
{
  RoundDown(A1, 0);
}
```

Where the 0 represents that you want to round to 0 decimal places.

[Excel Round function.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/round.php)

Comment: found it...sorry =ROUND(A1-0,051;0) pretty simple yes

Answer (score -2):

I really like this answer. This serves the purpose.

=IF(MOD(4.55; 1) > 0,55; ROUNDUP(4.55;0); ROUNDDOWN(4.55;0))

Comment: Please don't copy&paste others' posts and pass them off as your own: your answer seems lifted from @Eddy's answer, verbatim. This is considered inappropriate here.